# Add latitude and longitude column to existing data frame

Tags: python, pandas, nominatim

I am unable to add latitude and longitude column to existing data frame. I have extracted coordinates from one of the column **Restaurant_Location** from my data-set using below code.

```
location = [x for x in rest_df['Restaurant_Location'].unique().tolist() if type(x) == str]
latitude = []
longitude =  []
for i in range(0, len(location)):
    if(type(location[i]) == str):
        ctr=0
        while True:
            try:
                address = location[i] + ', Mumbai, India'
                geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="ny_explorer")
                loc = geolocator.geocode(address)
                latitude.append(loc.latitude)
                longitude.append(loc.longitude)
                print('The geographical coordinate of location are {}, {}.'.format(loc.latitude, loc.longitude))
            except:
                ctr+=1
                if(ctr==7):
                    print(i)
                    latitude.append(address)
                    longitude.append(address)
                    break
                continue
            break
```

I am able to get the desired **Output**

```
The geographical coordinate of location are 19.1840129, 72.8412155.
The geographical coordinate of location are 19.0583358, 72.8302669.
```

But after running above code successfully `rest_df.head()` is not showing **location_latitude** &   **location_longitude** columns in my data-frame, which I want to add in the data-frame. Also there are several other columns in my data-frame. Please let me know where I am doing mistake?

Comment: you say `res_df` does not have the new columns, but you never assign the values of both list `longitude` and `latitude` in your dataframe, at least with the code given here?

Comment: @Ben.T please guide me with a sample code on how to assign the values of both list `longitude` and `latitude` in my dataframe? as I am unable to figure-out.

Comment: if the lists have the same size than you dataframe, then `res_df['location_latitude'] = latitude`, outside of the loop for. Now because of all what you do with `unique` and then the `ctr` counter, I'm not sure this will work

Comment: @Ben.T I am getting `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index` when trying to run `res_df['location_latitude'] = latitude`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pice of code that should work, I deleted some stuff as I'm not sure why, but you can still put them back if you do other things in it. `new_df` should have all the rows from your original dataframe, and added the two columns you want. I have not been able to test as I don't have your data, so they might have typo but the idea is there

```
location = [x for x in rest_df['Restaurant_Location'].unique().tolist() 
            if type(x) == str]
latitude = []
longitude =  []
for i in range(0, len(location)):
    # remove things that does not seem usefull here
    try:
        address = location[i] + ', Mumbai, India'
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="ny_explorer")
        loc = geolocator.geocode(address)
        latitude.append(loc.latitude)
        longitude.append(loc.longitude)
        print('The geographical coordinate of location are {}, {}.'.format(loc.latitude, loc.longitude))
    except:
        # in the case the geolocator does not work, then add nan element to list
        # to keep the right size
        latitude.append(np.nan)
        longitude.append(np.nan)
# create a dataframe with the locatio, latitude and longitude
df_ = pd.DataFrame({'Restaurant_Location':location, 
                    'location_latitude': latitude,
                    'location_longitude':longitude})
# merge on Restaurant_Location with rest_df to get the column 
new_df = rest_df.merge(df_, on='Restaurant_Location', how='left')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is working now. I now understand my mistake that - I was not creating a new dataframe for `latitude` & `longitude` and passing the values. Also, I was not able to figure-out `merge`  function. Thanks a lot!